# vagrant hyperv the following settings shouldn't exist: memory

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v

Writing my vagrantfile running version 1.7.2 and using the hyperv provider I get the error:

the following settings shouldn't exist: memory

when I set:

```
config.vm.provider :hyperv do |v| 
     v.memory = 4096
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed per: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5260#issuecomment-72576686

I haven't seen an official timeline for 1.7.3. I looked around and decided that I didn't want to wait for the official release.

So if you can't wait (like me), then you can manually update using the files updated in the commit I pointed to above (these have also been merged into the master branch).

Assuming you've installed Vagrant 1.7.2 for windows, then you can just update the following 3 files on your machine:
 1. C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.7.2\plugins\providers\hyperv\action\import.rb
 2. C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.7.2\plugins\providers\hyperv\config.rb
 1. C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.7.2\plugins\providers\hyperv\scripts\import_vm.ps1

You'll grab the updated file content from here:
 1. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/plugins/providers/hyperv/action/import.rb
 2. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/plugins/providers/hyperv/config.rb
 3. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/plugins/providers/hyperv/scripts/import_vm.ps1

There's probably a more official way of pulling these recent changes onto your machine, but what I did was add .bak as a file extension to the 3 files on my machine, then went to the raw pages for the updated files on GitHub in the master branch of mitchellh/vagrant, copied and pasted them into new files.

Once that was done, I was able to successfully create VMs in hyperV with a customized vmname, memory and cpucount.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Vagrant docs for Hyper-V are at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/website/source/docs/hyperv/configuration.html.md